# Why do we need to find minimum energy in a protein chain?

Tags: proteins, energy

- [High–quality protein backbone reconstruction from alpha carbons using Gaussian mixture models](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jcc.23330)

The above research paper is about a software tool for reconstructing a protein's main chain model only from its alpha-carbon backbone (aka, C-alpha trace).

This tool provides two options: conversion (1) with energy minimization, and (2) without energy minimization.

- [Energy Minimization](https://www.intechopen.com/chapters/74105)

The above paper says that:

> ...
> The goal of energy Minimization is to find a set of coordinates representing the minimum energy conformation for the given structure.
> ...
> In molecular modeling we tend to are particularly curious about minimum points on the energy surface. Minimum energy arrangements of the atoms correspond to stable states of the system; any movement off from a minimum provides a configuration with a better energy.
> ...

I haven't understood the quote from the second paper.

Why do we need to know the minimum energy conformation of a protein chain? I.e., why do we want to do *energy minimization*?

Comment: The energy minimization is not only used for protein. If you want to calculate any property of your system (and want that property to persist), then you calculate it the minimal energy structure: minimum of potential energy surface.
I think that in 2, there is a typo: instead of *better*, could be *greater*.

Comment: @Camps, *I think that in 2, there is a typo: instead of better, could be greater.* --- This is exactly what is written in the paper.

Comment: I am not questioning what you wrote. My thought is that papers are not perfect, even after a proofreading, so, maybe that is an error.

Comment: Cross posted on [Bioinformatics SE](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/20052/why-do-we-need-to-find-minimum-energy-in-a-protein-chain)

Comment: @Tyberius, Yes, because this question is a month old, and no answer posted.

Answer (score 1):

[An answer was provided at Bioinformatics.SE](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/20055/3621).

This Community Wiki answer can be converted to a comment if someone wants to write a more detailed answer.